# Fix HTML Submenu

Tags: html, css

I can not open the submenu, I want to open the submenu when I hover over "Services" submenu, I think I have some mistakes in CSS.

I try to fix the menu using only CSS.

I have tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175196/html-css-horizontal-navigation-submenu-hover-wrong-displayed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066931/css-dropdown-menu-the-submenu-showed-on-hover-dissapears-while-you-browse-submen), Unfortunately, the problem has not been resolved.

This is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul a,
#cssmenu ul a:link,
#cssmenu ul a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: #848889;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  border-left: 3px solid #d7d8da;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #3dbd99;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #3dbd99;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
/* Sub Menu */
#cssmenu ul ul a:link,
#cssmenu ul ul a:visited {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: none;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d7d8da;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 13px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Services</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">S1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S1.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">S1.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">S2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-location-arrow"></i> Adress</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

can you help me please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not to use `visibility: hidden`, but instead `display:none` for the submenu ( changed that in the  `#cssmenu ul ul` rule in my snippet below).

Apart from that, you need a CSS rule that on hover of the parent `li` switches the direct child `ul` to `display: block`, with this rule:

```
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 1px;
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
/* Custom CSS Styles */
#cssmenu {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul a,
#cssmenu ul a:link,
#cssmenu ul a:visited {
  display: block;
  color: #848889;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  border-left: 3px solid #d7d8da;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  border-left: 3px solid #3dbd99;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  color: #3dbd99;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
/* Sub Menu */
#cssmenu ul ul a:link,
#cssmenu ul ul a:visited {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 180px;
  background: none;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d7d8da;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 13px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> Services</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">S1</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">S1.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">S1.2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">S2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-location-arrow"></i> Adress</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```